# Unexplained difference between explicitly invoking __enter__ on @contextmanager vs "with" statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, with-statement, contextmanager

I have a context manager type (`Connection`) and an `@contextmanager` decorated function that yields that type from within a `with` statement.

If I explicitly invoke `__enter__` on the decorated function, `__exit__` is invoked on `Connection` before it is returned.

This is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from contextlib import contextmanager


class Connection(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.closed = False

    def __enter__(self):
        print('Connection.__enter__')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('Connection.__exit__')
        self.closed = True
        return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}(closed={})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.closed)


@contextmanager
def connect():
    with Connection() as c:
        print('connect yielding connection')
        yield c
        print('connect yielded connection')


def context():
    print("connect explicit call to __enter__")
    c = connect().__enter__()
    print("got connection via __enter__", c)
    print()

    print("connect implicit call to __enter__ via with")
    with connect() as c:
        print("got connection in 'with'", c)
    print("connection after 'with'", c)
    print()

    print("Connection explicit call to __enter__")
    c = Connection().__enter__()
    print("got connection via __enter__", c)
    print()

    print("Connection implicit call to __enter__ via with")
    with Connection() as c:
        print("got connection in with", c)
    print("connection after 'with'", c)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    context()
```

When run this outputs:

```
connect explicit call to __enter__
Connection.__enter__
connect yielding connection
Connection.__exit__
got connection via __enter__ Connection(closed=True)

connect implicit call to __enter__ via with
Connection.__enter__
connect yielding connection
got connection in 'with' Connection(closed=False)
connect yielded connection
Connection.__exit__
connection after 'with' Connection(closed=True)

Connection explicit call to __enter__
Connection.__enter__
got connection via __enter__ Connection(closed=False)

Connection implicit call to __enter__ via with
Connection.__enter__
got connection in with Connection(closed=False)
Connection.__exit__
connection after 'with' Connection(closed=True)
```

Compare the sequence starting with "connect explicit call to __enter__" to "connect implicit call to __enter__ via with".

When I explicitly invoke `__enter__` on the `@contextmanager` decorated function, why is `Connection.__exit__` called before the connection is returned to me? And why is "connect yielded connection" never printed - so this means it is still at the yield statement and has not yet left the `with` block - so why was `__exit__` called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You discarded the context manager, so the generator object became eligible for reclamation. A generator's `__del__`* automatically calls `close` on the generator, which raises a `GeneratorExit` at the point of the last `yield`, ending the `with Connection() as c` block and triggering `c.__exit__`.

*technically, on Python 2, this actually happens in a lower-level cleanup routine than `__del__`.

Comment: Changing to hold onto the generator fixed it: `cm = connect(); c = cm.__enter__()`